# WPF and WinForms WebBrowser Control not processing HTTP 302 redirect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control, http-status-code-302

Im trying to display a webpage inside my application.

Both the WinForms WebBrowser & WPF WebBrowser controls are ignoring a 302 redirect.
The Webpage im displaying starts with a login page.

After login it performs a 302 redirect to display the next page. The browser is ignoring the 302 redirect and just displays the first page after login.

The CefSharp browser works great, but unfortunately its size of over 100MB makes it not suitable for my application.

Any way to get the native WebBrowser controls to work with a redirect?

Comment: Have you considered edge and webview or webview2? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf

Comment: You may want to add a User Agent Header to specify the Browser to use : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: @Andy I cant dictate that the client install Edge for this to work.

Comment: @jdweng Set it to what and how will that help?

Comment: The Server does different processing depending on the browser selected (User Agent).  Not sure which one will work.  What Browser is your default browser?  I believe CEFSharp is using you default browser User Agent.  So I would first try your Default Browser for the User Agent.

Comment: The webbrowser control is a thin wrapper around internet explorer. If you check your ie security settings. I guess they are currently set to high. That disables redirect. If setting security to medium is not acceptable to customers then you need a different browser control or to not use 302.